# Android InstallException: EOF Google MapsView "Hello Maps"

Tags: java, android

Eclipse isn't pointing out any errors in my code. Got an exception when I tried to run the emulator. Here's all my code.

HelloGoogleMaps.java

```
package com.example.hellogooglemaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;


public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    MapView mapView;
    ZoomControls mZoom;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;
    }



}
```

main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="my_api_key" //I have this in my program. Just not putting it in post.
```

/>

HelloGoogleMaps Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**EDIT** Debugging shows the following:

```
ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting
```

**EDIT 2** Console also gives this warning:

```
Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which    has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
```

**EDIT 3** It installs now but the app quits unexpectedly in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Close all emulators.  Restart Eclipse.  Refresh your project.  Right click your project, hover on Android Tools and select Fix Project Properties.  Look for a blank XML file that you didn't create and delete it if it exists.

One of these things should work.

Comment: Didn't work. I didn't see a blank XML file in the directory to the left in eclipse. "Failed to install HelloGoogleMaps.apk on device 'emulator-5556! (null)"

Comment: Where would this blank XML file be? Maybe i'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Also, I'm running Mac OSX. Not sure if that will make a difference.

Comment: It could be anywhere but should be with the other xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Do it step by step:

- Restart PC to make sure that no emulator process is running in the background
- Start eclipse
- clean the projects (all available)
- start your project

If this doesn't fix it, remove the app from the emulator and try to start it again.

If that doesn't fix it, you should try to delete the AVD and create a new one...

Comment: Dropped the API down to 10 as well as the AVD, and it installed. But then the application quits unexpectedly. "GoogleMapsView (process com.example.googlemapsview) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."